# Установка драйверов на сетевой адаптер DWA-172 в ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, установка, драйвер

Пытаюсь поставить драйвера на данный адаптер, следовал различным инструкциям из сети, не помогают, сетевой интерфейс адаптера не отображается в `ifconfig`. Подскажите, может я могу предоставить выводы каких либо команд для решения данного вопроса.

Comment: буквосочетание "dwa-172" не содержит никакой информации об устройстве. [получите vid и pid usb-устройства](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+vid%3Apid+usb-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0), и можете даже самостоятельно разыскать информацию в вашем любимом поисковике по запросу "ubuntu 1234:5678" (где "1234" - vendor id, а "5678" - product id вашего usb-устройства).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, официальный установщик в разделе "загрузки" [D-Link DWA-172](https://dlink.ru/ru/products/2/2430.html?ysclid=l7holu0pl7607270274)

содержит в себе файл

> ./install.sh

который при запуске автоматически должен вам поставить все драйвера, но т. к. *во 1-ых я забыл указать, на каком устройстве у меня стоит Ubuntu Server*, а *во 2-ых это Raspberry Pi 3B*, то установщиком просто не учтено, что он может быть запущен при архитектуре arm64, из-за чего возникают различные ошибки при его запуске на Raspberry. Покопавшись на форумах я понял, что при исполнении команды **`make`** (неоднократно исполняемой в установщике) в моём случае нужно указывать **ARCH=arm64** то есть получается:

> make ARCH=arm64

это позволит без ошибок произвести установку драйверов, другими словами требуется открыть файл установки и добавить ко всем **`make`** командам **ARCH=arm64** что позволит безошибочно произвести установку на Rapberry, после которой сразу появляется сетевой интерфейс.